# Which is the better client for Solr + PHP?

Tags: php, json, solr

I have two options

1. http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.solr.php
2. http://code.google.com/p/solr-php-client/

I read it somewhere that that 2) use JSON as output types whereas 1) use XML doc.

1. Isn't that a property of Solr which returns doc both in JSON and XML?
2. What other features do I have to consider before deciding?

Comment: It looks like both options are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I would actually recommend the other option, http://code.google.com/p/solr-php-client/ because it is the core PHP library used by the Drupal Solr plugin.

I think, like so many things, YMMV (Your Milage May Vary).  Looks like you may have had your question answered here: [Useful Thread](http://groups.google.com/group/php-solr-client/browse_thread/thread/1151f48faa3123b)

Comment: The useful thread is hidden behind a login. Can you please either post publicly available resources free from any TOS and also provide at least an abstract about what you think should be there in your answer?

Comment: Yes! solrPHPClient is well-done library and even supports Solr 1.4. However, it currently only supports up to Solr 4.x+. There's also some odd design, e.g. one-element array value of multivalue field will be converted to string, which is kinda superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the PECL Solr PHP extension and it worked nicely.

I'm considering using [Solarium](http://www.solarium-project.org/), because - while it is framework agnostic - it seams easy to integrate it in a Zend Framework project.

Comment: Solarium + 1, it's with better construct!

Comment: Does PERL solr or Solarium supports v1.4 ~ 3.x? Some production still runs old-version Solr.